I need to update my sdk to 34 in my react-native project because of play store new needs, i know how to update but not what should be update and why
My targetVersion is 33 and minVersion is 21, i know how to change it with android studio but i am not sure if i only need to update the targetVersion, should i update minVersion as well or anything else ?
gradle version is 7.4.1 and agp upgrade assistant can help me upgrade it but when it work my project won't launch again because of package error something about package name should'nt be in something.xml
same goes for kotlin my version is 1.8, should i update all this or not and why ?
I am not looking for a how but for a why, i am a junior and i don't have any senior to explain to me all this

The React Native Upgrade Helper is your friend.
Enter your current React Native Version and your Target Version.
Keep an eye on the android/build.gradle which will give you the corresponding targetSdkVersion for the current React Native Version.
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.70.0&to=0.74.5

ty, i didn't this exist but i didn't want to update react-native, but the api level of android, i know how to update the targetSDK but should i update min sdk as well and if i do should i update other things ?

The version of React Native has native code which needs to match up with the version in the build.gradle. Try and match up all versions that are recommended on the Upgrade Helper!
